# How can I sort DB2 results based on month and year parameter from separate column

Tags: sql, date, db2

I am using DB2.

I have a query that returns a specific date in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd

```
  SELECT DATE FROM ABC.DTS
```

Then I have devised another query that is supposed to return results that match the date returned above

```
SELECT COUNT(*)                           
FROM   ABC.ATY
WHERE  ID between 1 and 1000000000   
AND MONTH(PRS) = MONTH(from DTS)    
AND YEAR(PRS) = YEAR(from DTS)    
AND CKPYE = ' '
;
```

I am getting an error when I run the second query that says: `ILLEGAL SYMBOL "MONTH". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: XMLELEMENTXMLPI. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.56.`

How can I return the results that match the date that is returned from the first query?

Is there another route/strategy I need to instead of the one I am currently trying?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be joining the table `ABC.DTS`? Also, what is the datatype of `PRS`?

Comment: I figured I needed some sort of join, can you comment specifically on which type? and PRS is of type datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)                           
FROM   ABC.ATY
JOIN ABC.DTS ON MONTH(PRS) = MONTH(Date) AND YEAR(PRS) = YEAR(DATE)
WHERE  ID between 1 and 1000000000   
AND CKPYE = ' '
;
```

Comment: thanks, but it did not work. received this error: DATE IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.19.56

Comment: That would tell me that the `Date` field is not really a column... can you post your table schemas for both tables? That is also a reserved word, so that might be another issue here.

Comment: wait, im sorry haha that did work! I changed some of the table names around for purposes of posting this and forgot to change one back when querying it

Comment: Changed column names to protect the innocent. :-) Cool!